# UICollectionViewCell align to top of each row

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with cells of various sizes.  I am trying to implement a general layout that would have all the cells align to the top of each row (the built in flow layout aligns all the cells to the center of the row).

The cell with the greatest height would push all the cells down on the next row.

Is there an easy way to subclass the layout and implement this?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

https://github.com/sonsongithub/IntroduceCollectionView